# Creating a custom angular directive for tag and attribute combination?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Ok, here's the deal.

I created a custom directive for the `input` tag with custom validation for `input[type=ip]`:

```
.directive('input', function($q, $timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            if (attrs.type !== 'ip') return;
            var reg = new RegExp("^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$");
            ctrl.$asyncValidators.ip = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
                if (ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue)) {
                    return $q.when();
                }

                var def = $q.defer();
                if(reg.exec(modelValue)) {
                    def.resolve();
                } else {
                    def.reject();
                }

                return def.promise;
            };
        }
    };
});
```

This works fantasticaly and I plan on using it to create custom validations in the future.

The issue I'm having is with `input[type=file]`. In the view, it has no `ngModel` attribute. Angular does not like this. It's technically an `input` tag so it interprets the `input` directive... but that requires the `ngModel` attribute.

How can I fix this? How can I create custom `input` directives based upon the `type` attribute that don't break each other?

Can I make the `require: 'ngModel'` somehow options or something?

Comment: Yes ~ `require: '?ngModel'`. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-require-

Comment: @Phil won't the `ctrl` be null in this case? And there will be no controller that performs validation and thus no validators can be attached?

Comment: Just a remark, what's the reason to use asynchronous validators? This validation is made async artificaially

Comment: Yes, but isn't that what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

Phil's comment of using `?ngModel` fixed it. Everything working fine.